# Complicated search and replace in Vim or Sed

Tags: sed, grep, vim, search, replace

I have the following (yanked from my register to retain formatting, as it's probably the reason I'm here):

```
<li><span>Concrete Patching (</span><span
        style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; margin: 0.00px 0.00px; border: 0.00px solid #000000; transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px); -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px); width: 16.00px; height: 16.00px;"><img
          alt=""
          src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR4XmP4//8dAwAI2gLt+1m1FgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
          style="width: 16.00px; height: 16.00px; margin-left: -0.00px; margin-top: -0.00px; transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px); -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px);"
          title=""></span>)</li>
    <li><span>Paving (</span><span
        style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; margin: 0.00px 0.00px; border: 0.00px solid #000000; transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px); -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px); width: 16.00px; height: 16.00px;"><img
          alt=""
          src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR4XmP4//8tAwAI2ALsJ7n0vAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
          style="width: 16.00px; height: 16.00px; margin-left: -0.00px; margin-top: -0.00px; transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px); -webkit-transform: rotate(0.00rad) translateZ(0px);"
          title=""></span>)</li>
```

I would like that to become: `<li> Concrete Patching (flag) </li>`, that's it.

***EDIT:***
Should mention that the string inside of each `<li><span> (...` tag could any string.
I want to remove the initial `<span>` within each `<li>`, retain all up to `(`, then replace all up to `)` with `flag`. Sorry for not clarifying.

---

This pattern occurs throughout all files in a directory, so a batch job using `sed` would be ideal, but I'm not as confident with that. I've attempted it within a single `Vim` buffer utilizing `:%s/<C-r>"` to put the yanked register in the command, escaping what I know to escape (eg. `<\/span>`, `\r` for line break) but I'm defintely not doing it correctly.

If there's a plugin for easily doing `:%s` from a complicated yanked chunk like the above, I'd use it but none of them seem to respect regex patterns needed to properly do so the way I need.

I replace a lot of near identical text in my work and doing manual edits takes hours of time when I know it could take minutes with a regex pattern. Please feel free to offer any suggestions.

Comment: I'm assuming that you just want the first line to be changed and leave the rest of the block as is? Or do you want to replace the entire block in the input example with the single line?

Comment: I think my answer is wrong, unaccept it so I can reformulate it.

Comment: confirmed @schrodigerscatcuriosity lol

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I edited my question a bit better, hopefully it makes more sense - sorry about that

Comment: You have two similar blocks, `<li><span>Concrete Patching...` and `<li><span>Paving ...`, shouldn't be the output `<li> Concrete Patching (flag) </li><li> Paving (flag) </li>`?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yes, but the blocks aren't always next to each other and most have other html between them too ...

Comment: Try now, I've updated the answer.

Comment: don't use a regex for this, use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose this approach, using the `-z` option of `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed -z 's;<li><span>\([^(]*\)(</span><span[^<]*<img[^>]*></span>);<li> \1(flag) ;g' file
<li> Concrete Patching (flag) </li>
    <li> Paving (flag) </li>
```

This takes into account that "Concrete Patching" could be any string.

```
-z, --null-data
                 separate lines by NUL characters
```

Comment: this worked, as far as I can tell at least - you're a life saver

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
sed '/Concrete Patching/ s/<span>/ /; s/(<\/span><span/(flag) <\/li>/' your_file
```

The way it's working is as follows:

- For any line containing `Concrete Patching`, perform the following 2
  substitutions: 1) replace the first `<span>` with a space and 2) replace the
  `(<\/span><span/` with `(flag) <\li>`

Once you've confirmed it does what you want, just add the `-i` to do the
substitution in-place:

```
sed -i '/Concrete Patching/ s/<span>/ /; s/(<\/span><span/(flag) <\/li>/' your_file
```

Comment: Thank you! This is going to save me hours of time, I'll try it out now. Is there a way to tell sed to retain the '/Concrete Patching/' part, as if it was just a simple string? That's the only part that'd be different throughout.

Comment: @WilliamGreer Do you mean "Concrete Patching" could be other string?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yes exactly